# Creating a summary table with mean +/- SD and significance levels for 2 way ANOVA in R software

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 treatments, and 19 genotypes with 3 replications with 10 parameters. I want to create a summary table showing the mean+/- SD along with the letters indicating the significance levels as seen in this reference[image] image. Please help me by providing the code for R software. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have your dataset, we don't.  So it's going to be difficult to give immediately useful advice.  Also, you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: @Limey, hereby I am sharing you a google drive link with my sample data- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zj9eLqVbM9x24MdJaaBvMhw09nykA28K/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=109494900882301496529&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Limey I tried doing and i could succeed in only adding mean +/- SE, but i am facing trouble to add tukey significance letters. I am also attaching my code and data file. Please help me in resolving the issue.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KBSGCwWfk8y5Wav9u5-iS317uvbhRKXk?usp=drive_link